# Array Costs in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, arrays

Why is storing in an array the first time in solidity costs higher than the other times? The other times it has a constant cost which is less than the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm sure this has come up before. If someone can find a previous answer then please duplicate... )

From the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), Appendix G, you'll see the following line:

> G<sub>sset</sub> - 20000 - Paid for an SSTORE operation when the storage value is set to
>   non-zero from zero.

Meaning the first time you write a variable to storage, it's more expensive by 20,000 gas. Subsequent updates to the variable are cheaper.

**Edit:**

As JBrouwer has pointed out in the comments, for <s>structs</s> arrays you also need to store the length, so you're writing to two initially-zeroed storage slots rather than one, equating to 40,000 extra gas.

Comment: If you store an array you also have to store in the length slot (which is initially set to zero) and the value you want to store - this is hence at least 40k gas.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good point :-) If you add it as an answer I'll definitely upvote.

Comment: Include it in your answer =) You hence write to 2 slots not 1.

Comment: "For structs you also need to store the length" - I assume you mean array here instead of struct? Because `struct x = {uint a};` can be stored in a single slot (like `x someStructStorageValue`)

Comment: @JBrouwer - You're right - I meant arrays not structs! Changed :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not unique to arrays, but to any state-variable in your contract.

Changing from zero to non-zero costs more gas than changing from non-zero to non-zero.